# PHP rand vs mt_rand vs openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a random string and was doing some research and found the following link:

http://golearnphp.com/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-and-openssl_random_pseudo_bytes/

```
function generateRandom($length) {
    $validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $myKeeper = '';
    for ($n = 1; $n < $length; $n++) {
        $whichCharacter = rand(0, strlen($validCharacters) - 1);
        $myKeeper .= $validCharacters{$whichCharacter};
    }
    return $myKeeper;
}

function generateRandomdMT($length) {
    $validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $myKeeper = '';
    for ($n = 1; $n < $length; $n++) {
        $whichCharacter = mt_rand(0, strlen($validCharacters) - 1);
        $myKeeper .= $validCharacters{$whichCharacter};
    }
    return $myKeeper;
}

$start = microtime(true);
echo htmlentities(generateRandom(100000));
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
echo htmlentities(generateRandomdMT(100000));
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
echo htmlentities(substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(100000)), 0, 100000));
var_dump(microtime(true) - $start);
```

In the post the writer is saying that openssl_random_pseudo_bytes is significant faster then the other two. Is this true? Is openssl_random_pseudo_bytes really that much faster? Is that the correct way to test the "fastness" of functions?

Comment: Would you like me to test it for you?

Comment: Is the piece of code he is using the right way to test the speed of a function?

Answer (score 0):

[openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) created to be crypto strong(check the second param). Rand is old rand function with small period of repeating. MT_Rand is better than rand but not supposed to be used by crypto systems.

I bet that the difference between execution time do not impact on your application.

Also. Those functions return different results. First two return string with 36 possible letters. And third one returns string with 64 possible symbols. Result of two first function is shorter than third one.

If you are making optimization to speed up your application first thing that you should to know: how to profile your code.

Comment: Actually, [the second parameter, as currently implemented, is not reliable](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/6#issuecomment-119564973).

Answer (score 0):

> In the post the writer is saying that openssl_random_pseudo_bytes is significant faster then the other two. Is this true?

In normal situations `mt_rand()` is significantly faster than `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

It's only slower in the test code you've posted because you are comparing apples and oranges.  For `rand()` and `mt_rand()` you are using complex functions which build up a string one byte at a time, whereas for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` you're using the raw binary stream it produces with `base64_encode()` which is going to be much faster.

If you could get a raw binary stream out of mt_rand() or rand(), or a sequence of numbers 0 to 63 from `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, you could do an apples to apples comparison.

In my testing, I found `mt_rand()` about 4 times as fast as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)` when I used `unpack('V', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4) & "\xff\xff\xff\x7f")` in order to get an equivalent output to `mt_rand()`.  However this is still technically an apples to oranges situation because I'm doing additional processing on one in order to match it to the other, just in the opposite direction to you.

Answer (score 0):

The time you asked this question, there was a bug report here > https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70014 (php 5.6.10) It seems to be fixed in new versions of PHP.

My experience using it has always been **unnecessary**, I prefer Mt_Rand() but if you are generating random values for encryption purposes like I am doing, then do not use it, you should use random_bytes() ref. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php